# Why does reinstalling and uninstalling Homebrew fail?

Tags: python, ruby, git, homebrew

It has been taking me a long time, and I still don't have a solution to solve a problem I have installing Homebrew.

When I type `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"`, I get:

```
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
Ok
```

I typed `rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup`, and got this error:

```
rm: /usr/local/Cellar: Directory not empty
```

When I enter this directory there is no file. How can I remove that directory?

I also tried `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar`.

Comment: Did you tried chmod then rm ?

Comment: No, what number in chmod command should I type  ?

Comment: What does `brew doctor` say?

Comment: when I typed `brew doctor`, I've got this message : _/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:17:in `require': no such file to load -- global (LoadError)
 from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:17_

Comment: sorry was on phone & don't know the min of 15 char , it's chmod -R 777

Answer (score 0):

Carefull, the url changed from raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go to raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install.

It don't seems to be your error but could help if you decide yo reinstall homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `.git` directory exist? Not to be confused with the `git` directory (without the dot). If hidden files are not visible, running the command `ls -a` will list all files.

I had the same error and checked and I realized that `/usr/local/.git` did not exist so I created it using the command `mkdir /usr/local/.git` and ran the installer again and everything worked. If the directory does not exist, it cannot write to it, and it is somewhat confusing because there could be a directory named `git` in there too, which is the Git application, whereas the `.git` directory stores information that Git uses.

If it does exist and there's nothing in it, you could try removing it with `rm -r .git` then recreating it.